# Lottery game, add css class based on numerical range

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a lottery random number generator and have it working, all I want to do is change the background colour of the ball varying on what number range its called between. The second block of code is what I have come up with so far.

For example

o 1-9: White
o 10-19: Blue
o 20-29: Ping,
o 30-39: Green,
o 40-49: Yellow

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <!-- meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

      <title>NRONLINE - Buckinghamshire Web Design, Digital Marketing Workshops and Kofax Consultancy</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
 body {
    background: #444;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 690px;
    height: 100px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 36px;
}

ul li:nth-child(5n) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.ball-placeholder {
    background: #222222;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #222222 0%, black 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #222222), color-stop(100%, black));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #222222 0%, black 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #222222 0%, black 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #222222 0%, black 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #222222 0%, black 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 );
}


.next-ball, .play-again {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
}

.next-ball {
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #7ac9ed;
}

.play-again {
    display: none;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background: #d74d2f;
}

.white-ball {
    background: #fff;
    color:#101010;
}

.blue-ball {
    background: #99ccff;
    color:#101010;
}

.pink-ball {
    background: #ffccff;
    color:#101010;
}

.green-ball {
    background: #00cc66;
    color:#101010;
}

.yellow-ball {
    background: #fac600;
    color:#101010;
}
    </style>   
    </head>
    <body role="document">

        <ul class="ball-placeholders">
          <li class="ball-placeholder"></li>
          <li class="ball-placeholder"></li>
          <li class="ball-placeholder"></li>
          <li class="ball-placeholder"></li>
          <li class="ball-placeholder"></li>
          <li class="ball-placeholder"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="lottery"></ul>
        <button class="next-ball">Next Ball</button>
        <button class="play-again">Play Again!</button>






    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var arr = new Array();
    $('.next-ball').on('click', function(){
      //generate random number between 1 and 50
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*50 ) + 1;
      // array to store css class references
      var classList = ["white-ball", "blue-ball", "pink-ball", "green-ball", "yellow-ball"];
      console.log(random);
      //if index of random number is less than 50
      if( arr.indexOf(random) == -1){
        //generate random number
        arr.push(random);
        //add css class to lottery-ball class relevant to array value range
        $('.lottery').append('<li class="lottery-ball ' + classList[Math.floor(random/10)] + '">' + random + '</li>');
      }
      // if the number already exists ignore and generate a new number
      else {
        console.log(random);
      }
      console.log(arr);
      //if lottery number calls is greater than 5 then switch button classes and send an alert to the user 
      if ( $('.lottery').children().length > 5 ) {
        $('.next-ball').hide();
        $('.play-again').show();
        alert('Did You Win?');
      }

    });
    //If once the game is finished the user chooses to play again switch button classes 
    $('.play-again').on('click', function(){
      $('.lottery').children().remove();
      arr = [];
      $('.next-ball').show();
      $('.play-again').hide();
    });
    </script>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Does your idea work (no because of a syntax error from the looks of it) ? Please put this on jsfiddle or similar

Comment: You can't just do `&& <= 49`, you have to put the left side value again, `&& arr.indexOf(random) <= 49`. Though you could save the value in a variable first so you do not have to keep calling indexOf

Comment: link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nronline/sx4g27de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative could be CSS attribute selectors. We could use the 'starts with' selector `^`, which will target all elements whose attribute in question... well, starts with a particular string.

Say we give each `li` representing a ball a `data-*` attribute equal to its number. Then we can style their backgrounds like so:

```
li[data-number^=0] {
  /*target numbers less than 10
    Need to append 0 in front of numbers  <10
    for this to work*/
  background: white;
}

li[data-number^=1] {
  /*target numbers in the teens*/
  background: blue;
}

li[data-number^=2] {
  /*target numbers in the twenties*/
  background:pink;
}
 /*...and so on...*/
```

Then the JS is somewhat simplified to:

```
if (arr.indexOf(random) == -1) {
  arr.push(random);
  $('.lottery').append('<li class="lottery-ball" data-number="' + (random < 10 ? '0' : '') + random + '">' + random + '</li>';
}
```

EDIT: [here's a link](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) for other types of attribute selectors.

Comment: Hi guys just wanted to add that I had already resolved two errors since posting the jsfiddle. Although I took a different approach to solving the 0 value issue and also a repeat number being called. Code also edited above. 

Basically i started the random number call from 1 and in the event a duplicate is called the generator fires again (obviously this makes no difference to the user experience as they wont see it), thanks for all your input

Answer (score 2):

Your idea should work, but since the only thing that changes is the class of the li it could be more compact.  Here I've stored the class names in an array, and used the first digit of the ball number - `Math.floor(random/10)` to find the right element.  Also your indexOf line had a bug - a return of zero from indexOf means the element was found at the start of the array, so check for -1.

```
  var classList = ["white-ball", "blue-ball", "pink-ball", "green-ball", "yellow-ball"];

  if( arr.indexOf(random) == -1){
    arr.push(random);
    $('.lottery').append('<li class="lottery-ball ' + classList[Math.floor(random/10)] + '">' + random + '</li>');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks guys, James the array idea is much tidier than my initial approach. Muchly appreciated. best regards

Comment: really nice job